# How to sha1 hash a c# login application

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I want to make my password as hash password like sha1 I tried to make it `PassLogin = sha1(@PassLogin)` but it is not working

Here is my code

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM LoginReport where UserLogin = @UserLogin and PassLogin = @PassLogin", conn))
{
    conn.Open();

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserLogin", txtUser.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PassLogin", txtPass.Text);
    SqlDataReader Dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (Dr.HasRows == true)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Successfully Login");
        Form1 FormReports = new Form1();                         
        FormReports.ShowDialog();
        Application.Exit();

    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Check username and password again!!");
    }
}
```

Comment: `HASHBYTES('SHA1', @PassLogin)` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms174415.aspx But using an unsalted SHA1 hash to store a password is a very bad thing.

Comment: Using SHA1 gives poor security, even with a salt. You should use an algorithm like PBKDF2 with a high iteration count: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're not actually hashing the value before assigning it as parameter.

You may first want to try hashing the input string, see the included code (**not tested!**) for an example how to do this:

```
public static string GenerateSaltedSHA1(string plainTextString)
{
      HashAlgorithm algorithm = new SHA1Managed();
      var saltBytes = GenerateSalt(4);
      var plainTextBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(plainTextString);

      var plainTextWithSaltBytes = AppendByteArray(plainTextBytes, saltBytes);
      var saltedSHA1Bytes = algorithm.ComputeHash(plainTextWithSaltBytes);
      var saltedSHA1WithAppendedSaltBytes = AppendByteArrays(saltedSHA1Bytes, saltBytes);

      return "{SSHA}" + Convert.ToBase64String(saltedSHA1WithAppendedSaltBytes);
} 

private static byte[] GenerateSalt(int saltSize)
{
     var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
     var buff = new byte[saltSize];
     rng.GetBytes(buff);
     return buff; 
}

private static byte[] AppendByteArray(byte[] byteArray1, byte[] byteArray2)
{
    var byteArrayResult =
            new byte[byteArray1.Length + byteArray2.Length];

    for (var i = 0; i < byteArray1.Length; i++)
         byteArrayResult[i] = byteArray1[i];
    for (var i = 0; i < byteArray2.Length; i++)
         byteArrayResult[byteArray1.Length + i] = byteArray2[i];

    return byteArrayResult;
}
```

I would like to advise that you use a stronger hashing algorithm than SHA1 since it's become easy with current technology to create huge rainbow tables to easily find the original string of a hash. Also please salt your hash!